# Delete multiple rows in a ListVIew

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I've got a Lsitview populated with CheckedTextViews. My goal is to be able to delete multiple rows at onece, if possible with `MultiChoiceModeListener`. 
To use it, I have to set the ListView `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`.

The frist problem is now: I cant just chek the checkboxes now, because the listview isnt `ChOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` anymore.

I hade the idear to set it `CHOICE MODE MULTIPLE` and just set an `OnItemClickListener`for the ListView, but then the `ChoiceModeMultiple` and its Method `onItemStateChaed` Method always gets called, even if i just wanna check a checkbox in my App.

Any solutions on how to fix that?

**The Code (layout is the ListVIew) :**

```
layout.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {

        if (!list_items.contains(list.get(i))) {
            count++;
            list_items.add(list.get(i));
            actionMode.setTitle(count + " items selected");
        } else if (list_items.contains(list.get(i))) {
            count--;
            list_items.remove(list.get(i));
            actionMode.setTitle(count + " items selected");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you apply an `onItemClickListener` for the checking and an `onItemLongClickListener` for selection of multiple rows?

Comment: i tried, but sadly the app crashed

Comment: What kind of crash? Did you get an Exception? What did your log say?

Comment: Look into my new edit

Comment: Sry, but that crash report does not tell much... Does the app start at all?

Comment: Ye it starts, but when i perform the onLongItemCklick it crashes...

Comment: It does. Thats strange

Comment: update!  my right crash report says:  attempted to start selection mode for CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL but no choice mode callback was supplied. Call setMultiChoiceModeListener to set a callback.

Comment: Well, there you have it... Have a look in the API and implement your MultiChoiceModeListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example, please refer this and solve

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listItems);
        arrayList.add("one");
        arrayList.add("two");
        arrayList.add("three");
        arrayList.add("four");
        arrayList.add("five");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_layout,R.id.textView,arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);


        list.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long l, boolean b) {

                count = count+1;
                actionMode.setTitle(count + " items selected");
                arrayList2.add(arrayList.get(position));

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu,menu);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                {

                    case R.id.delete_id:

                        for(String msg : arrayList2) {
                            arrayAdapter.remove(msg);

                        }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            count=0;
                            actionMode.finish();
                        return true;


                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                adapterView.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```